# SQL Server Manager crashes when viewing user permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2016

I have a problem that I can't seem to find a solution to.
When I click on a user in a specific location, SQL Server Manager 2016 crashes to an error dialoge. This is a repeatable incident.
I'm on Server 2012 R2.

To trigger the error:
Connect to Server Object Explorer, log in with sa user. Open Databases, right click the "test" DB, select Properties. Select the Permissions page. 
In the field "users or roles", when I press the eligible user, which is called test_dbo, SQL crashes with an error message: "SSMS has stopped working".
The user has been given proper rights (at least as fas as I know), and is DBOwner. It is possible view the user's rights every other place I have tried.

When the error dialoge shows, pressing "Show problem details" shows:

---

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: Ssms.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 2015.130.16106.4
  Problem Signature 03: 58891f43
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1087.0
  Problem Signature 06: 583e5abb
  Problem Signature 07: 3526
  Problem Signature 08: 21
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentOutOfRange
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1044
  Additional Information 1: 36fe
  Additional Information 2: 36fe547341409026b0499dff2436b6e0
  Additional Information 3: 044d
  Additional Information 4: 044dbaa475e5e7b5545c7fb67a640214

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

---

I have tried a limited amount of things to remedy this, but nothing has worked. This includes reinstalling .NET, which one site suggested.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: If the SQL server engine is not 2016, try connecting under another version of SSMS and check if all the data is present and consistent. Otherwise report a bug to Microsoft. `System.ArgumentOutOfRange` means some integer value is not in the expected range, for example, that user's ID is not registered elsewhere.

Comment: I see no reason why the SQL engine would not be 2016, since this is a fairly new installation, with no prior SQL versions where installed. It was not upgraded, but rather had a straight 2016 installation. Anyhow, how do I check which engine is in use?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't open SQL management studio at all after upgrade of OS from 2008 r2 to 2012 R2.Installed the latest version of net 4.8 & also got rid of UAC. No more problems. 
This also got rid of issue opening server manager.